# is it possible to chain .css().fadeIn()?

Tags: jquery

I get an error when I try this so was wondering if there is actually a way to do this or do I just have to go with;

```
$(this).css('color', 'red');
$(this).fadeIn();
```

Comment: the answer is (literally) in your question... *is it possible to chain .css().fadeIn()*

Comment: You probably used `$(this).css("color").fadeIn()` or similar which the only way you'd get an error and the code you gave is then misleading because it's not the same you tried with chaining.

Comment: hey guys, apologies. just asked a silly question. think my machine had cached and was playing tricks. free to close this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.You can chain.

Pass the second parameter as the value of the CSS property to set it.

```
$(this).css("color","red").fadeIn();
```

But, Make sure you are having a jQuery object in $(this). How are you getting this object ? On an event of an element ( which is hidden )?

Example :

```
$("#someButtonID").click(function(){      
    $("#someDivID").css("color","red").fadeIn();
});
```

Worksing sample : http://jsfiddle.net/mak3G/1/

Answer (score 2):

In case of [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) you have two options:

- one argument e.g. `css('color')` in which case you will get css color property value, this cannot be chained
- two arguments e.g. `css('color', '#000')`, which is used to set value and which can be chained because it returns jQuery object

To sum up:

```
var value = $(this).css('color'); // get color value
$(this).css('color', '#000').fadeIn(); // set color value and fadeIn
```

Answer (score 0):

I receive no errors when stringing these together.

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
$(a).css('position','fixed').fadeIn();
```

Returns:

```
[<div style="position: fixed; opacity: 0; display: block; "></div>]
```